# Issue on Checkbox with Custom Option Page

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, options, settings-api

I am trying to use a checkbox on Custom Option page by using Setting API. Every thing works fine at back-end and I can update the checkbox states by registering the settings.But when I would like to see the result on the page I am getting same result **" The checkbox has not been checked."** even so the checkboxed has been checked and updated on the options.php and my custom option page!

Here is what I have for updating and saving the checkbox state:

```
public  function contactprice_setting(){
    $options = get_option('price_display_options');
    $html = '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_contactprice" name="price_display_options[checkbox_contactprice]" value="1"' . checked( 1, $options['checkbox_contactprice'], false ) . '/>';  
    $html .= '<label for="checkbox_contactprice">Uncheck The Text Box</label>';
    echo $html;
    }
```

As I said this part works fine but when I try to output the result in index.php as:

```
<?php if( $input_examples['checkbox_contactprice'] == '1' ) { ?>  
    <p>The checkbox checkbox has been checked.</p>  
<?php } else { ?>  
    <p>The checkbox has not been checked.</p>  
<?php } // end if ?>
```

As I mentioned I am getting the **"The checkbox has not been checked."** in both checked or on checked situation. Can you please let me know why I am getting this?

Comment: What is the code that sets `$input_examples`? Or, perhaps, what is `var_dump($input_examples);`?

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum, using this code <?php var_dump($input_examples);?>  in index.php the result is pint out as "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... using this code  in
>   index.php the result is "null"

Since the code referenced is `var_dump($input_examples);` that means that `$input_examples` hasn't been set or it [out of scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) where you are trying to use it. You will need to add ...

```
$input_examples = get_option('price_display_options'); // maybe not the right key
```

... to your code before this line:

```
if( $input_examples['checkbox_contactprice'] == '1' ) {
```

I am guessing at the option name but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing string "1" using == operator you should compare strings using [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function as shown in the following code :

```
<?php if( strcmp( $input_examples['checkbox_contactprice'], '1' ) != 0 ) { ?>  
    <p>The checkbox has been checked.</p>  
<?php } else { ?>  
    <p>The checkbox has not been checked.</p>  
<?php } // end if ?>
```

Comment: Hi Vinod, Thanks for your reply but still not working! I mean I am getting same "The checkbox has not been checked."

Comment: @MonaCoder I have updated my answer.

Comment: that's wired! still not working!